# Return single result from v-for based on key value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have a `v-for` loop to display a single result at a time based on the selected `:key` from another data value `counter`. While this works great, the problem lies with adding `<transitions>` when the value updates, causing both to appear briefly and jump about the page while the previous item transition disappears.

From what I can see, the issue is that all the `tag` results are still there on the DOM from the `v-for` and simply transitioning between the two.

Is there a better way to achieve this so only the `{{tag}}` values are updated based on the key?

```
<div v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.id">
     <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="tag.id == counter">
        <div class="tag-col--prod-img mb-4">
          <img class="img-fluid" :src="tag.thumb" />
        </div>
        <h5 class="mb-5">{{tag.heading}}</h5>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <h1>{{ tag.title }}</h1>
        </div>
        <h2 class="mb-3">{{ tag.price }}</h2>
        <p class="mb-4">
          {{tag.detail}}
        </p>
        <a :href="tag.link" target="_blank">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">View product</button>
        </a>
       </div>
      </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use v-for if you only want to display a single element from the list?

Comment: @bernie I'm not too sure. Is there a better way to determine what `{{tag}}` elements will show based on `tag.id` matching the `counter` value key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it and take advantage of Vue's computed properties:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <h5 class="mb-5">{{activeTag.heading}}</h5>
  <!-- The rest -->
</transition>
```

Add this to your component:

```
computed: {
  activeTag() {
    return this.tags.find(({ id }) => id === this.counter);
  }
}
```

`activeTag` will be reevaluated each time `tags` or `counter` changes, causing an update to the DOM elements referencing `activeTag`'s properties.

Comment: Excellent! I ended referencing the key rather than the index to remove the `v-for` completely. You led me in the right direction so thank you!